# Unix File Permissions

Tags: unix, file-permissions

I have a file `xyz` with permissions 440 with owner "a" and group "b".

group b contains guest user

now i am user C and i want to read the contents of the file xyz. is there any possible way for that?

Answer (score 2):

You should just add user C to group B.

Here's the best resource I've found on it: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's posible, you can use [Access Control List](http://beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1038-ubuntu-804-access-control-lists) to allow users or groups to access some file or directory.

• Example to allow user **c** to **read** file **xyz** :

```
setfacl -m u:c:r /home/a/xyz
```

> The **-m** is to modify the acl and the "**u**" is for the user which is specifically named, "**c**", followed by the rights and the file.

• or example to allow group **b** to **read, write, execute** file **xyz** : #

```
setfacl -m g:b:rwx /home/a/xyz
```

> If you want to configure a directory so that all files that are created will inherit the acls of the directory you would use the "**d**" option before the group.

• To remove rights use the "**x**" option.

```
setfacl -x g:b /home/a/xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put user C into group B.